# Synchronization in java/android

Tags: java, android, multithreading, synchronization, touch

I am trying to line up touch move event in android. The following is a snippet of the handling event in a SurfaceView that covers the whole screen. The purpose of the code is to perform detection which node of the graph is clicked. But for our purpose, we will ignore the graph. I only hope to produce "start to look for node" and "finished looking for node" in pairs without 2 (or more) "starts" or two "finished" outputted consecutively.

```
//recognizing and handling touch event
    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent( MotionEvent event) {
        final float x = event.getX(), y = event.getY();
        int action = MotionEventCompat.getActionMasked(event);
        String DEBUG_TAG = "Debug";
        switch(action) {
            case (MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) :
                return true;
            case (MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE) :
                    Thread thread = new Thread(){
                        public void run(){
                            test(x, y);
                        }
                    };
                    thread.start();
                //}
                return true;
            case (MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) :
                temp = null;
                return true;
            default :
                return super.onTouchEvent(event);
        }
    }
    private synchronized void test(float x,float y) {
        Log.d("Debug","starting to look for node");
        Node n = myGraph.detectCollision(x,y, currentColor);
        Log.d("Debug","finished looking for nodes");
    }
```

However, as you might have guessed, it does not work as intended i.e. I could get "start looking for nodes"; "start looking for nodes"; "finished looking for nodes"; "finished looking for nodes" rather than "start looking for nodes"; "finished looking for nodes";"start looking for nodes"; "finished looking for nodes" in the log output. However, if I replace the content of `test(float x, float y)` by a simple `Thread.sleep(1000)` rather than `Node n = myGraph.detectCollision(x,y,currentColor);` , it seems to work well. How is changing the content of `test(x,y)` mess up my synchronization? Any pointer will be deeply appreciated.

For your convenience in testing, I will attach the (hopefully bug-free) code for MyGraph, Node and Coordinate (aka 2Dvector) class:

```
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.util.Log;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Random;


public class MyGraph{
    //logic side- the graph object that interacts with users
    public static final int DISRESPECT = -1;
    public static final int MORECOLOR = -3;
    private final float EPSILON = 0.003f;
    private ArrayList<Node> graphNodes; //maximum of 13 vertices
    private int nVertices = 0;
    private int score = 50;
    int maxColor = 0;
    HashMap<Integer,Integer> colorPopulation;
    double boundx, boundy, C;

    public double getBoundx() {
        return boundx;
    }

    public void setBoundx(double boundx) {
        this.boundx = boundx;
    }

    public double getBoundy() {
        return boundy;
    }

    public void setBoundy(double boundy) {
        this.boundy = boundy;
    }

    public double getC() {
        return C;
    }

    public void setC(double c) {
        C = c;
    }

    public int getScore() {
        return score;
    }
    public void setScore(int score) {
        this.score = score;
    }
    public int getnVertices() {
        return nVertices;
    }
    public MyGraph(){
        graphNodes = new ArrayList<Node>();
        colorPopulation = new HashMap<Integer,Integer>(15);
    }
    public ArrayList<Node> getGraphNodes() {
        return graphNodes;
    }

    //add a new node into the graph
    //also set the id of that node
    public void addNode(Node n){
        graphNodes.add(n);
        n.setId(nVertices++);
    }
    public void addEdge(Node n1, Node n2){
        n1.addEdge(n2);
        n2.addEdge(n1);
    }

    //randomly generate a graph with parsity
    public void randomGenerating(double parse){ //parse is between 0 and 1
        Random gen = new Random(System.currentTimeMillis());
        int tempNVertices = gen.nextInt(8) + 5; //CHANGE HERE TO BECOME A RANDOM NUMBER
        for(int i = 0; i< tempNVertices; i++){
            Node n = new Node();
            //change here to get non-colliding coordinates in initial state
            float x = gen.nextFloat();
            float y = gen.nextFloat();
            n.setCoord((float)(x*boundx),(float)(y*boundy));
            addNode(n);
        }
        for(int i = 0; i < tempNVertices; i++){
            for(int j = i + 1; j < tempNVertices; j++){
                if(gen.nextDouble() < parse){
                    addEdge(graphNodes.get(i),graphNodes.get(j));
                }
            }
        }


    }
    public Node detectCollision(float cx, float cy, int selectedColor){
        Coordinates target = new Coordinates(cx,cy);
        for(int i = 0; i < graphNodes.size(); i++)
            if (graphNodes.get(i).contains(target)) {
                if(!colorPopulation.containsKey(selectedColor)){
                    colorPopulation.put(selectedColor,0);
                }
                if(colorPopulation.get(selectedColor) == 0){
                    score += MORECOLOR;
                }
                int color = graphNodes.get(i).getColor();
                if(color != -1 && colorPopulation.get(color) == 1 && color != selectedColor){
                    score -= MORECOLOR;
                }
                int diff = graphNodes.get(i).setColor(selectedColor);
                colorPopulation.put(selectedColor,colorPopulation.get(selectedColor)+1);
                if(color != -1)
                    colorPopulation.put(color,colorPopulation.get(color) - 1);
                score += diff;
                return graphNodes.get(i);
            }
        return null;

    }

}
```

Node class:

```
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Paint;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.LinkedList;

public class Node {
    private ArrayList<Node> incidentList; //maximum 12 vertices
    private ArrayList<Integer> weight;
    private int color;
    public Coordinates coord;
    private Coordinates disp;

    public Coordinates getDisp() {
        return disp;
    }

    public void setDisp(float x, float y) {
        disp.setX(x);
        disp.setY(y);
    }
    public void setDisp(Coordinates d) {
        disp = d;
    }

    private int id;
    public Node(){
        incidentList = new ArrayList<Node>(15);
        weight = new ArrayList<Integer>(15);
        color = -1;
        coord = new Coordinates(0,0);
        disp = new Coordinates(0,0);
        id = -1;
    }
    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public ArrayList<Node> getIncidentList() {
        return incidentList;
    }
    public void addEdge(Node n) {
        incidentList.add(n);
        weight.add(1);
    }
    public void removeEdge(Node n){
        int index = incidentList.indexOf(n);
        incidentList.remove(n);
        weight.remove(index);
    }
    public int getColor() {
        return color;
    }
    public int setColor(int color) {
        if (color == getColor())
            return 0;
        int diff = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < incidentList.size(); i++) {
            if (incidentList.get(i).getColor() == getColor() && getColor() != -1)
                diff -= MyGraph.DISRESPECT;
            else if (incidentList.get(i).getColor() == color)
                diff += MyGraph.DISRESPECT;
        }

        this.color = color;
        return diff;
    }
    public Coordinates getCoord() {
        return coord;
    }
    public void setCoord(float x, float y) {
        coord.setX(x);
        coord.setY(y);
    }
    public int getDegree(){
        return incidentList.size();
    }

    public boolean isAdjacent(Node n){
        return incidentList.contains(n);
    }

}
```

Coordinate class:

```
public class Coordinates {
    private float x;
    private float y;
    public Coordinates(float xx, float yy){
        x = xx; y = yy;
    }
    public float getX() {
        return x;
    }
    public void setX(float x) {
        this.x = x;
    }
    public float getY() {
        return y;
    }
    public void setY(float y) {
        this.y = y;
    }
    public String toString(){
        return x+" "+y;
    }
    public Coordinates subtract(Coordinates c){
        return new Coordinates(x-c.x, y - c.y);
    }
    public Coordinates add(Coordinates c){
        return new Coordinates(x + c.x, y + c.y);
    }
    public Coordinates unit(){
        if(length() == 0)
            return new Coordinates(0.000001f,0.0000001f);
        else
            return new Coordinates(x/(float)Math.sqrt(x*x + y*y),y/(float)Math.sqrt(y*y + x*x));
    }
    public float length(){
        return (float)Math.sqrt(x*x + y*y);
    }
    public float distance(Coordinates c){
        return (float) Math.sqrt((x-c.x)*(x-c.x) + (y-c.y)*(y-c.y));
    }
    public Coordinates scale(float k){
        return new Coordinates(k*x,k*y);
    }
}
```

Note that you can easily generate a random graph by calling `MyGraph g = new MyGraph(); g.randomGenerating(0.5);`

Comment: "it does not work" - what is the behavior you are observing?

Comment: I get "starting to look for node", "starting to look for node","finished looking for nodes","finished looking for nodes" rather than "starting to look for node", "finished looking for nodes", "starting to look for node", "finished looking for nodes"---- the `synchronized` does not seem to have any effect

Comment: I'm not familiar with android. but it seems that different objects are being syncrhonized on. try making the method `static synchronized` (you'll need to add `myGraph` etc to the method parameters)

Comment: Briefly, you are creating two Thread objects. A synchronized method is one thing to help cause threads to be synchronized but its not going to solve the problem. You can also set flags to pause resume each thread so that its this ones turn then that ones turn. Tick tock goes the clock. Tick tock .. tick tock. One two one two. If you want to know why sleep changes things, you should make it your time to do lots of research on it now so you really get it.

Comment: @bayou.io tried, but it seems to produce the same results, even when the function is static (baffling).

Comment: @CmosBattery how exactly do you synch the threads in such way? some examples will help! Just looking for directions here. I will not vote down anyone's answer, even if it doesn't help.